# Is it possible to use Protractor to test the value of a variable not model-bound to the DOM?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I'm relatively new to Angular and new (today) to Protractor, so I'm not exactly sure how to ask this question - thus I not quite sure if there is a duplicate out there. Below is a very simplified version of a much larger, much more complex application we are developing, but the basic idea is the same.

Let's say I have a simple web page:

```
<input id="my-input" ng-model="myValue">
<button id="submit-button" ng-click="doSomething()">
    Click Me
</button>
```

Controlled by a simplified angular app:

```
// some-angular-app.js

$scope.myValue = "";
$scope.computedValue = null;

$scope.doSomething = function() {
    $scope.computedValue = "Hello World";
}
```

Essentially, when you click on the button, it triggers a function which manipulates variables in your app. In our case (as above), the variables (i.e. `$scope.computedValue`) are not bound to the DOM in any way - they are actually compiled and passed to a JSON request to be consumed by our API. However, I want to test those values -- something like:

```
// some-protractor-test.js

describe('form submission', function() {
    it('should corretly set the computed value', function() {
        browser.get('http://our.awesome-web.page');
        element(by.css("#my-input")).sendKeys("Hello Input");
        element(by.css("#submit-button")).click();

        // ??? how to check that computedValue === "Hello World" ???
    });
});
```

Is is possible to use Protractor to check the state of our data in this manner, or must all interaction with the Angular app be handled through DOM elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is something you need to check in your unit-tests of services, directives or controllers. Think about your `protractor` end-to-end tests as about a *real user* who opened your app in the browser, clicked some buttons and observed some data - black-box approach, not diving into technical details, all made through protractor-browser interactions. `protractor` was designed to automate browser actions faking a real user - staying on the higher-level.

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about this for a couple of days I find your answer to be truly good advice - we should work to separate our end-to-end tests from our functional- and unit- tests. What this does is basically expose that I don't have good enough coverage in my unit tests :)

Comment: I've got a question about that:
as our project grew, we started to spin off a sub project containing only our custom input directives. Now I'm at the point to write protractor tests only for those inputs, which is pretty low level (bindings, clicking, event handling...). Would you still consider your answere valid for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use evaluate() to retrieve the model value:

```
groupCode.evaluate('groupCode').then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```